# How to write to a nested array inside an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array, inside an object

```
const gameItemFlagMap = await functions.fetchGameItemFlagMap(item_id);
const items = [];
const object = {
    flags: [null],
}

if (gameItemFlagMap[i].item_flag_id) { 
    for (let j = 0; j < gameItemFlagMap.length; j++) { 
        // object -> flags -> flags_id & flags_identifier
        string = "object.flags.flag_id_"
        object_name = string.concat(i);
        [object_name] = [gameItemFlagMap[i].item_flag_id];

        gameItemFlags = await functions.fetchGameItemFlags(gameItemFlagMap[i].item_flag_id);
        string = "object.flags.flag_identifier_";
        object_name = string.concat(i);
        [object_name] = [gameItemFlags[0].flag_identifier];   
    }
    items.push(object);
}
```

I'm not where to put the index value when writing an array inside an object or if my syntax is correct.

**Added Notes:**

The data that will be pulled from a database and has about 20 rows, but only 3-4 rows are associated with my object at any given time. The for loop is currently set up to pull the correct data associated with the object in question.

Inside my object, I have most of the data that only needs to return a single value, but when pulling from itemFlags I need to be able to store several values inside an array attached to this object

In the following screenshot: https://puu.sh/E86hG/e17338f20e.png you can see the object containing multiple values of data and the flags is an empty array within this object. My goal is to add data to that array using a for loop but couldn't find out the correct syntax to do so. You can see `flag_count` is set to 4, which means the object is expecting 4 entries to be written into that nested flags array.

**Sample Data**

item_id: 17
flag_id: 1
flag_identifier: "identifier A"

item_id: 17
flag_id: 2
flag_identifier: "identifier B"

item_id: 17
flag_id: 3
flag_identifier: "identifier C"

item_id: 24
flag_id: 4
flag_identifier: "identifier D"

item_id: 24
flag_id: 5
flag_identifier: "identifier E"

item_id: 24
flag_id: 6
flag_identifier: "identifier F"

The example source of data has 6 possible sets of data to import, we want both the `flag_id` and `flag_identifier`. When the script runs on say Item 17, then 3 sets of information associating with that item_id will be written to the nested array. If I called item 24, then 4, 5, 6, D, E, F will be written.

Comment: Could you include some mock data so we can test this? As well as the expected result

Comment: Could you give us an example of your input and output. Not sure what your requirements are here

Comment: added additional notes

Comment: Require more information. Some sample data would be nice

Comment: sorry, i have added sample data now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com) to do it in one line. Consider the following code:

```
const input = [
 {
  item_id: 17,
  flag_id: 1,
  flag_identifier: "identifier A"
 },
 {
  item_id: 17,
  flag_id: 2,
  flag_identifier: "identifier B"
 },
 {
  item_id: 17,
  flag_id: 3,
  flag_identifier: "identifier C"
 },
 {
  item_id: 24,
  flag_id: 4,
  flag_identifier: "identifier D"
 },
 {
  item_id: 24,
  flag_id: 5,
  flag_identifier: "identifier E"
 },
 {
  item_id: 24,
  flag_id: 6,
  flag_identifier: "identifier F"
 }
]

const output = _.groupBy(input, 'item_id')

/* Out for sample input would be
{
"17":[
      {"item_id":17,"flag_id":1,"flag_identifier":"identifier A"}, 
      {"item_id":17,"flag_id":2,"flag_identifier":"identifier B"}, 
      {"item_id":17,"flag_id":3,"flag_identifier":"identifier C"}
     ],

"24":[
      {"item_id":24,"flag_id":4,"flag_identifier":"identifier D"}, 
      {"item_id":24,"flag_id":5,"flag_identifier":"identifier E"}, 
      {"item_id":24,"flag_id":6,"flag_identifier":"identifier F"}
     ]
}
*/
```

Comment: I need to know how to add the data inside a nested array within an object..

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output? I might be able to understand your question better that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your problem into two steps. First group the objects of the same item_id present in an array and after that push it into new array. Below is a simple representation of that process.

```
const input = [
{
 item_id: 17,
 flag_id: 1,
 flag_identifier: "identifier A"
},
{
 item_id: 17,
 flag_id: 2,
 flag_identifier: "identifier B"
},
{
 item_id: 17,
 flag_id: 3,
 flag_identifier: "identifier C"
},
{
 item_id: 24,
 flag_id: 4,
 flag_identifier: "identifier D"
},
{
 item_id: 24,
 flag_id: 5,
 flag_identifier: "identifier E"
},
{
 item_id: 24,
 flag_id: 6,
 flag_identifier: "identifier F"
}];

//grouping the objects with same item_id
let data = {}

input.forEach((item) => {
  const flagData = {
    flag_id: item.flag_id,
    flag_identifier: item.flag_identifier,
  }

  if (!data[item.item_id]) {
      const val = {
        id: item.item_id,
        flags: [flagData]
      };

     data[item.item_id] = val;

    } else {
      data[item.item_id].flags = [...data[item.item_id].flags, flagData];
  }
})
//pushing the grouped values in new array
let ans = [];

 Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
   ans = [...ans, data[key]];
 });
 /*Output would be like     
[{
  flags: [
    0: {flag_id: 1, flag_identifier: "identifier A"}
    1: {flag_id: 2, flag_identifier: "identifier B"}
    2: {flag_id: 3, flag_identifier: "identifier C"}
  ],
  id: 17,
 },
 {
  {id: 24, flags: Array(3)}
 }
*/
```